# SPOOL objects_log.log PROMPT SCRIPT: / /.sql @.sql

Tags: database, oracle, shell, sqlplus

I am reviewing some code. It contains a .sql file which contains this

```
****SPOOL install_cg_objects_log.log
PROMPT SCRIPT: /cg/synonyms/cretate_synonyms_for_cg.sql
@cg/sy/cretate_synonyms_for_cg.sql
PROMPT SCRIPT: /cg/packages/in.sql
@cg/packages/in.sql
PROMPT SCRIPT:/cg/triggers/tr.sql
@cg/triggers/trg.sql
SPOOL OFF****
```

Can anybody please explain me what this script is doing.

Answer (score 1):

That `*.sql` file you have is intended to be executed in `sqlplus` (oracle command-line utility)

1. **SPOOL** stores query results in a specified file - create sort of a log file.
2. **PROMPT** displays a message in `sqlplus` environment
3. **@** executes a script stored in a file (e.g `@/somepath/scriptfile.sql`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what does **** means here, Just pretending you used it here for making it clear start and end of the code. 
So, let's elaborate your code.

**SPOOL filename.log** --To Stores query results in a file which you've specified after space.

**PROMPT "Some message"** --To represents the runtime text messages which you want to display while execution.

**@** --Here this sign used to execute the .sql from SQL> prompt of your given path, Its like, you're calling multiple .sql files from the main.sql file.

**.sql** --It's a script which contains a group of multiple DML, DDL, DCL statements and other Oracle object definitions.

```
[oracle@OLE1 Desktop]$ vi yourmainfile.sql 
SPOOL install_cg_objects_log.log
PROMPT SCRIPT: /cg/synonyms/cretate_synonyms_for_cg.sql
select 'test' from dual;
PROMPT SCRIPT: /cg/packages/in.sql
select sysdate from dual;
PROMPT SCRIPT:/cg/triggers/tr.sql
select * from dual;
--@/cg/triggers/tr.sql
SPOOL OFF

[oracle@OLE1 Desktop]$ 
[oracle@OLE1 Desktop]$ sqlplus -s scott/tiger
@yourmainfile.sql
SCRIPT: /cg/synonyms/cretate_synonyms_for_cg.sql

'TES
----
test

SCRIPT: /cg/packages/in.sql

SYSDATE
---------
12-JUL-17

SCRIPT:/cg/triggers/tr.sql

D
-
X

exit
[oracle@OLE1 Desktop]$
```